# SQL Server 2012 Native Client returns missing DLL error on install

Tags: sql, dll

OS: Windows 7 Pro SP1

Whenever I try to install the SQL Server 2012 Native Client x64 the install process gets to the end, the "removing backup files" stage then throws up this error:

"There is a problem with this Windows Installer Package.  A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run.  Contact your support personnel or package vendor"

Then when I click OK (I have no other option) it rolls everything back and uninstalls.  The computer has all updates installed.  Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: I figured it out.  I copied sqlncli11.dll from system32 on a working machine to the broken machine, re-ran the installer for 2012 Native Client and it didn't throw up any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running 64 bit Windows 7?
What is result of this command?:

```
wmic os get osarchitecture
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I figured it out. I copied sqlncli11.dll from system32 on a working machine to the broken machine, re-ran the installer for 2012 Native Client and it didn't throw up any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now, and [this comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/716480/sql-server-2012-native-client-returns-missing-dll-error-on-install#comment890336_716488) was the solution:

> I copied sqlncli11.dll from system32 on a working machine to the broken machine, re-ran the installer for 2012 Native Client and it didn't throw up any errors

(Making as answer since comments might vanish without warning or trace.)